# INNO - checking file is installed with function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;

Tags: inno-setup, pascal

I'm new to Inno, but want to check '{pf32}\Google\Drive\googledrivesync.exe' is installed before install.

However, the code does not pick up {pf32} as it does in Check: for a file.
New some can you assist please
Michael

```
[Code]
function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
var  FilePath3, FP1: String;
begin
//Result := FileExists(FilePath3);
//FP1:= {pf32}    FilePath3:= '\Google\Drive\googledrivesync.exe'
if not FileExists({pf32} + FilePath3) Then
     begin                MsgBox({pf32} + FilePath3 + 'Google Drive not installed    correctly - Setup will now exit -                                        Please reinstall Google Drive!',       mbError, MB_OK);
  abort;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [`ExpandConstant`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_expandconstant) in order to...well...expand constants. :-)

```
function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
var  
  FilePath3: String;
  PFDir: string;
begin
  PFDir := ExpandConstant('{pf32}');
  FilePath3:= '\Google\Drive\googledrivesync.exe'
  Result := FileExists(PFDir + FilePath3);
  if not Result then
  begin                
    MsgBox(PFDir + FilePath3 + #13#13 + 
        'Google Drive not installed' +
        'correctly - Setup will now exit.'#13 +
        'Please reinstall Google Drive!',       mbError, MB_OK);
    Abort;
  end;
end;
```

NOTE: I don't recall off-hand if `ExpandConstant` includes the trailing backslash or not, so you'll have to test. If so, you'll need to remove the backslash that starts `FilePath3`.

Comment: Thank you so much Ken that has made all the difference and all now works GREAT !.

Comment: Constants may or may not contain a trailing backslash already (it varies from system to system and where you're reading it from).  `ExpandConstant` itself however will automatically collapse two backslashes into one following a constant, so the *correct* way to write it is at minimum `ExpandConstant('{pf32}\')` (and remove the first backslash from FilePath3) -- but it's easier to put the entire rest of FilePath3 into the parameter as well.